# Getting insert options even though item is configured to have none

Tags: templates, branch

I'm working on a clients site and I am currently facing a weird behavior, when right clicking items on the item tree to add a new child item, I am getting options to insert items of different template types even though that I manually cleared the insert options for that item, I even cleared them for the standard values of that items template and restored the insert options for that item to default, but I am still getting those options, something that I noticed and could be of help, is that all the items under the site node including the site node itself have the ability to add the same types of items, even though when going through any items insert options you would find that they are empty.

What could I be missing? and how can I remove these unwanted insert options.

Comment: Have you checked insert options of your base templates?

Comment: Have you looked at insert rules?

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko it's based on the standard template in Sitecore,

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel also the insert rules have nothing selected

Comment: @Muradious, Do you have any patch up on 'uiGetMasters' pipeline - 'GetInsertRules' - processor..Use 'admin/showconfig.aspx' to find if any.

Comment: @BalajiKuppuswamy I checked it out and it seems that it is not calling any custom code, here is the processor line

<processor mode="on" type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetMasters.GetInsertRules, Sitecore.Kernel"/>

Comment: @Muradious, can you clear your cache thr /admin/cache.aspx or try from different browser. ?

Comment: Thanks everyone, It turns out that it was being caused by rules set under system>settings>Rules>Insert Options, did not know there was such a thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the cause to my issue was lying within the rules set under Sitecore -> System -> Settings -> Rules -> Insert Option Rules,

These rules make it easier to set insert options for a large set of items using simple logic, without having to set them in the standard values for those items templates.

Following is a sample rule that will reflect on the home item and all of its descendants except the settings item and its descendants to add 2 insert options, one to add a "Page" Item and the other to add a "Blogs Page" item:

```
"where" the item is "Home" item or one of its descendants
"and" "except where" the item is the "Settings" item or one of its descendants 
add "Page" insert option
"and" add "Blogs Page" insert option
```

Comment: For everyone's benefit, please elaborate on your answer describing how this was set up. Just a brief example.

Comment: @MarkCassidy sure thing